# Native OAuth in Cordova application

Tags: cordova, oauth, cordova-plugins

I'm looking for a neat way to do social sign in - Google, Facebook, etc. - in a Cordova application.

Most plugins I've come across use a popup window implementation to authenticate via the web. A lot of users may not be signed in to Facebook (for example) on their mobile browser, and just use the FB app on their device.

Is there a recommended way to approach this?